# asp.net page wise objects

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net

I have a large report in asp.net(Say sales report summary). I needn't to change any data upto refresh button pressed in that page(Static once its fetched) but need to give datasource for my datatable on pagination/sorting/grouping etc... If i'm calling query for each execution it will take about long time(In my test environment itself 5 minutes) So i'm willing to make it to temporary table. When he clicks the button temperory table will get filled. On page load i'll take data from this table only. But temporary table wont work if i'm not saving the connection for that page(Its connection oriented). I'm ready to use session for this connection but if the user sees the same page in two tabs both page will give same output. So i need the connection in ViewState or some thing like this. But at that time its telling you need to serialize the object(This is the error). How can i make a connection in page wise? Or any other solution? Sending full data via hidden field/ ViewState won't be a good idea.

Thanking you
binesh Nambiar C

Answer (score 0):

if its not a web application you can try using static variables. though its not a good practice but in your case i think it will solve the problem.
For further queries please show some code.

Or you can do one more thing. After fetching the data you can use getrange/add range depending upon ur sorting etc. and keep it in different list items and bind particular list items for different criteria's.

Comment: I'm using static variable for my windows application. I'm learning asp.net(Its behaviours in practical scenarios). At that time I got the problem. My requirement is one database connection for one page. Not even in one connection for one user/browser.